# Why is there current flow in the sub-circuits?

Tags: current, parallel, series, theory

I'm struggling with the theory of this(unusual) circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZAyCH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The load receives no power at all, due to the voltages cancelling out, yet the parallel sub-circuits voltages do not cancel out, and enormous current flows in each sub circuit. I dont understand why current in the whole circuit(even in the sub-circuits) is not equal to zero? If the voltage at node Vx is V1 - V4 = 0, likewise with Vy being V4 - V1 = 0.

I'm trying to understand how this is physically possible(for current to flow or shorting out in the sub-circuits) while the potentials are opposing one another, I tried looking at each branch and how it's possible for current to flow there but it's just difficult.

The reason why I think current flows in the sub-circuits, is because of them being shorted.  But still lost with the concept while analyzing.

Comment: The answer is simple. If there is a difference in potential (in voltage) between two points and if there is a path for a current to flow the current will flow. But if potential difference is 0 no current can flow. In your sub-circuits 1 there is a potential difference between V1 and V2 (6V) so the current must flow 6V/1 miliohm = 6000A

Comment: It flows in a loop around each sub-circuit.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1) Use [Thévenin's Theorem](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-10/thevenins-theorem/) to mathematically derive the Thévenin equivalent circuit for subcircuit V1, V2, Ri_1, and Ri_2. (Hint: The Thévenin equivalent should be 6 VDC in series with 250 μΩ).

Step 2) Use Thévenin's Theorem to mathematically derive the Thévenin equivalent circuit for subcircuit V3, V4, Ri_3, and Ri_4. (Hint: The Thévenin equivalent should be 6 VDC in series with 250 μΩ).

Step 3) Redraw the circuit, replacing the two subcircuits with their Thévenin equivalent circuits. From the **Load** resistor's perspective, this simplified circuit is equivalent to the original circuit.

Step 4) Use [Kirchhoff's Voltage Law](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-6/kirchhoffs-voltage-law-kvl/) (KVL) to calculate the current in the simplified and equivalent series circuit. (Hint: Your calculated current should be zero amps.)

So the **Load** resistor has zero amps flowing through it, and each subcircuit (in the original circuit) is a 6 kA current loop.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: I wasn't going to bother doing a full derivation and settle with a handwavy argument that we know the load current is zero because the two sub-circuits are identical and so the voltage across the load resistor will be zero, but I decided that it would probably not help very much, so full derivation it is.

---

Lets ignore the ground node that you have placed - there is only one of it, so it is doing nothing. Also, lets label the node between \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ as \$V_u\$, and the node between \$R_3\$ and \$R_4\$ as \$V_w\$.

It is then worth a reminder of what a potential difference is. It is the difference in voltage between any two nodes. The 9V battery has a potential difference at its positive terminal of 9V referenced to its negative terminal.

---

Lets first consider the sub-circuit individually - you can't always do this, in fact frequently you can't, but because the two are identical, I know that I can. You have 6V dropped across effectively a 1mOhm resistor. As a result you are going to get large currents - 6kA worth.

Lets try to work out the voltage at the node \$V_u\$ that I defined earlier with respect to node \$V_x\$, or to put it another way, the potential difference \$V_{ux}\$.

Well, we know from Kirchoffs Current Law that the sum of all currents on all braches at a node equals zero. So what are the currents into the node U? Well, there is the load current, the current through \$R_1\$ and the current through \$R_2\$. Lets put this in a calculation:

$$I_{R_1} + I_{R_2} + I_{load} = 0$$

So what are these currents. Well, lets work them out. First \$I_{R_1}\$

$$I_{R_1} = \frac{V_{R_1}}{R_1} = \frac{V_u - (V_x-9)}{R_1} = \frac{V_u - V_x + 9}{500\mu\Omega} $$

Then \$I_{R_2}\$

$$I_{R_2} = \frac{V_{R_2}}{R_2} = \frac{V_u - (V_x-3)}{R_2} = \frac{V_u - V_x + 3}{500\mu\Omega} $$

Bringing that all together:

$$I_{load(u)} = -\frac{V_u - V_x + 3}{500\mu\Omega} - \frac{V_u - V_x + 9}{500\mu\Omega} = \frac{-(V_u - V_x + 3) - (V_u - V_x + 9)}{500\mu\Omega} = \frac{-2V_u + 2V_x - 12)}{500\mu\Omega} = \frac{V_x - V_u -6}{1m\Omega}$$

Do the same with the other subsystem - you will get the same equation but with \$V_y\$ and \$V_w\$ instead - i.e:

$$I_{load(v)} = \frac{V_y - V_w -6}{1m\Omega}$$

---

Now we have analysed each subsystem, lets calculate what the load current is. We know that the current flowing through load resistor will be equal in magnitude on each side - because currents through a series branch are always equal.

$$\begin{align}
I_{load(u)} &= I_{load(v)}\\\\
\frac{V_x - V_u -6}{1m\Omega} &= \frac{V_y - V_w -6}{1m\Omega}\\\\
V_x - V_u &= V_y - V_w \tag{1}\\
\end{align}$$

If we look at the connection between \$V_x\$ and \$V_y\$ we can see that they are directly connected. That is to say \$V_x = V_y\$. So, substituting that in to (1), we get:

$$\begin{align}
V_y - V_u &= V_y - V_w\\\\
V_u &= V_w \tag{2}\\
\end{align}$$

We know then work out the current through the load is:

$$I_{load} = \frac{V_{load}}{R_{load}} = \frac{V_{uw}}{2k\Omega}= \frac{V_{u}-V_{w}}{2k\Omega} \tag{3}$$

So substituting (2) into (3) we get:

$$I_{load}= \frac{0}{2k\Omega}=0A$$

We can see then that there is no current through the load.

---

You can also then work out the current flowing in each sub-circuit. Remember we now know that the load current is zero which means each sub-circuit is effectively independent. You should be able to work out that the voltage over \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ is \$9-3 = 6V\$. So we can say that the current is:

$$I = \frac{6}{R_1+R_2} = \frac{6}{1m\Omega}=6kA $$

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to understand is to consider effect of each supply individually.

Using superposition.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmvge5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

\$500\mu\ \parallel\ 500\mu\ = 250\mu\$

\$250\mu \ s\ 2k \approx 2k\$

\$2k \parallel\ 500\mu\ \approx 500\mu\$

\$500\mu \ s\ 500\mu = 1m\$

\$I_T = \frac{V_1}{R_T}  = \frac{9V}{1m\Omega} = 9kA \$

Current flow is inversely proportional to resistance, so the majority flows through \$Ri_2\$ with approximately:
\$ I_{Load_1\ (MAX)} = \frac {500\mu\Omega}{2k\Omega}\ \times \ 9kA = 2.25mA\$ (current division) going through the load resistor.

Now 2.25mA on 9kA is meaningless (0.000025%).  But 2.25mA on the load resistor would be 4.5V.

Similarly: The effect of V2 is \$I_T = 3kA \$, \$ I_{Load_2} = 0.75mA\$.  Equivalent resistance is the same.

V1 and V2 work against each other so current in each branch is 9kA - 3kA = 6kA (ignoring 3mA going through load).

Same analysis works for V3 and V4, but polarity changes, so:

$$I_{Load} = 2.25mA + 0.75mA - 2.25mA - 0.75mA = 0A$$

Or:

$$V_{Load} = 4.5V + 1.5V - 4.5V - 1.5V = 0V$$

But each source has 6kA flowing through them.  All the power is wasted in sources.

Comment: *"Current flows through the path of least resistance"* - this isn't true.

Answer (score 0):

> I dont understand why current in the whole circuit(even in the
>   sub-circuits) is not equal to zero?

Step by step:

(1) Consider just one of the sub-circuits:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYmUWQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Clearly, there is a current \$I_1\$ circulating clockwise equal to

$$I_1 =  \frac{9\mathrm{V} - 3\mathrm{V}}{0.5\mathrm{m\Omega} + 0.5\mathrm{m\Omega}} = \frac{6\mathrm{V}}{1\mathrm{m\Omega}} = 6\mathrm{kA}$$

(2) Consider two of these sub-circuits that are not connected.  They both have \$6\mathrm{kA}\$ current circulating clockwise.

(3) Connect a wire between these two sub-circuits as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQodme.png)</sup>

This does not change the operation of the independent sub-circuits, however, we can now define the voltage *between* the two bottom nodes.

Now, *if* there is a non-zero voltage difference between the two bottom nodes, one node is more positive than the other.

Thus, if we exchange the position of the two sub-circuits, the polarity of the voltage across the two bottom nodes will reverse.

But consider; since the two sub-circuits are *identical*, it is impossible to distinguish between the original configuration and the swapped configuration and thus we should not expect the voltage between the two bottom nodes to change if the sub-circuits are swapped.

The only voltage consistent with this is \$0 \mathrm{V}\$ and so we conclude that there is zero volts between the bottom two nodes.

A load resistor placed across zero volts will have zero current through and so, connecting a load resistor between the bottom two nodes does not change the operation of the circuit.

In summary, both sub-circuits have \$6\mathrm{kA}\$ current circulating clockwise but there is zero current through the load resistor for the reason that the two sub-circuits are identical.